# Visual Studio Showing Bug that Doesn't Exist

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Im having a problem where Visual Studio is underlining code that Im pretty confident is not in error (ie. it compiles and runs).  Im using Visual Studios Professional 2013 and C++ is the language.  Here is my codes:

WindowMgr.h file:

```
class Screen;
class WindowMgr {
public:
    void clear(int ind);
private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens;

// there's some other stuff in here too
};
```

Screen.h file:

```
#include "WindowMgr.h"

class Screen {
    friend void WindowMgr::clear(int ind);
private:
    std::string privateVal;

// theres some other stuff in here
};
```

WindowMgr.cpp file:

```
#include "Screen.h"

WindowMgr::clear(int ind) {
    Screen &s = screens[i];

    // this is where the error is:
    // VS telling me WindowMgr cant access privateVal
    s.privateVal = "";
}
```

As I said, this code compiles and runs, as I would expect because the `clear` method is a friend of `Screen`.  However, VS is underlining the call to `privateVal`, telling me that it is inaccessible.  This is mostly just annoying, but if anybody has any ideas of how to fix I would be appreciative.

Things I have tried so far:  Cleaning the solution and rebuilding.  Closing VS and reopening.  Turning off my laptop and then turning it back on again.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010, I've had the IDE show me red squiggles in **comments** even... It's just off at times and yeah, it's a bug in the IDE. Deleting the IntelliSense cache files can sometimes help.

Comment: The IDE is just a tool. Use its guidence when it is helpful. Ignore it when it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug with older versions of Visual Studio, and that newer versions have incrementally fixed the issue.

Since you're using the Professional version, you might want to see if any update packs for Visual Studio 2013 are available; if not, you may wish to consider getting a license for Visual Studio 2015, depending on what your school/company is willing to provide. Worst case scenario, you can try using the Community Version of Visual Studio (which is free) though I don't know if that'll violate any functionality/license requirements you have.

Comment: Or he could just ignore the "red squiggles" as being unreliable - which is what they are..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Generally speaking, I don't usually treat "Ignoring it" as an acceptable answer unless all other options have been exhausted and found wanting. False Positives in Intellisense clutter the IDE, and make real errors harder to trace.

Comment: Sure. I don't disagree. But you really should complain to Microsoft then and get them to fix their shit. What else can you do besides that and ignoring it?

Comment: unfortunately I got VS as a student and no longer can get the Pro version for free.  I suppose I should just update to the most recent Community version - it's not really a dealbreaker obviously but it does bother me that and, as you say, it clutters up the IDE

Answer (score 0):

The parser that Visual Studio uses to give you "red squiggles" is not the real compiler. So compile your code and see if it is ok.

Just because your IDE indicates a problem does not mean there really is one. Treat IDE hints as nothing more than that - hints.

Comment: More specifically, IntelliSense (the source of the "red squiggles") uses a modified version of the EDG frontend, which is completely separate from Microsoft's compiler which was developed entirely in-house.